# How to parse checked/unchecked checkboxes in PDF file?

Tags: python, pdf, checkbox

I have a PDF file which needs to be parsed. That file contains checkboxes. I need to know which box is checked and which is unchecked after I parsed the PDF.

I mostly use Python, so I tried `pdfminer/pdf2txt` package in Python. Using that package, I was able to convert the PDF to HTML which contains those same checkboxes, but I am unable to see which checkbox is checked and which is not after I converted the file into HTML.
Has anyone ever did this type of operation before or has any ideas how to do this?
Following is an example of what I want to convert into HTML/text or any other format suitable for parsing.
[image]

Comment: hello @Andriy, any update on this ?